How to print only the opening tag of an element in etree?
Given an Element from etree, I would like to print only the opening tag. This would be immensely useful for debugging.
For example:
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> elem = etree.fromstring(b'''<bbq taste="awful" smell="amazing">
... <food type="hot dogs" />
... <food type="hamburgers" condition="burnt" />
... </bbq>''')

If I want to print this element I can use etree.tostring, but it can only print the full tree, even if it'd take up 10 screens:
>>> print(etree.tostring(elem).decode())
<bbq taste="awful" smell="amazing">
<food type="hot dogs"/>
<food type="hamburgers" condition="burnt"/>
</bbq>
>>>

What I would like is something like this:
>>> print(etree.tostring(elem, open_tag_only=True).decode())
<bbq taste="awful" smell="amazing">
>>>


Well, if the XML is attribute centric even the start tag can contain a lot of or more information than you need for a particular purpose so just write your own function for whatever serialization purpose you have.

You can get the opening tag with the following. I don't think there is anything to get the opening tag directly, so this is just using other attributes to build the wanted output:
print(f'<{elem.tag} {" ".join([f"{k}={quoteattr(v)}" for k, v in elem.attrib.items()])}>')
The .tag attribute is used to get the tag of the element, so here, as elem is the root element, elem.tag will be bbq.
The xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr function is used to properly escape attribute values (to correctly handle cases where there is a special character (&quot for example) in the attribute value - you'll need to import it with from xml.sax.saxutils import quoteattr though).
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from xml.sax.saxutils import quoteattr
>>> elem = etree.fromstring(b'<bbq taste="awful" smell="amazing"><food type="hot dogs"/><food type="hamburgers" condition="burnt"/></bbq>')
>>> print(f'<{elem.tag} {" ".join([f"{k}={quoteattr(v)}" for k, v in elem.attrib.items()])}>')
<bbq taste="awful" smell="amazing">


Thanks. I was hoping there's a way to let lxml do more of the heavy lifting, but I I guess this will suffice. It would probably print things wrong if the attribute value has a " in it, but I didn't check. By the way, attrib is unnecessary, I believe elem.items() works directly.

@NeatNit Yes indeed, &quot and special characters like that will cause some trouble. I edited the answer, adding the xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr function, to handle these cases. And yes, elem.items() is suffient as it returns what seems to be a list of tuples, which works with this method too ;)
